# Entanglement and the Interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I understand that entanglement is irreversible, due to loss of information. I also believe that, at least sometimes, it can be produced using an appropriate "interaction hamiltonian", $\hat{H}_{int}$, such that the time evolution operator, for a two object system, can be represented as something like $e^{i/\hbar (\hat{H}_1\otimes\hat{I} + \hat{I}\otimes\hat{H}_2 + \hat{H}_{int})}$ where $\hat{H}_1$ (the Hamiltonian for one object) and $\hat{H}_2$ (the Hamiltonian for the other object) are both Hermitian and $[\hat{H}_1,\hat{H}_2] = 0$, but $\hat{H}_{int}$ commutes with neither of the other Hamiltonian terms.

Must this $\hat{H}_{int}$ be non-hermitian, so that the time evolution operator is not unitary, which would make the entanglement produced by $\hat{H}_{int}$ reversible?

Comment: Entanglement *is* reversible. It is collapse (i.e. projecting the wavefunction onto a subspace of the Hilbert space) which is irreversible, but what you wrote in the OP has nothing to do with collapse. From a more practical point of view, entanglement can be *difficult* to reverse, much like playing a game of pool in an effort to get all the balls back in their original triangular configuration.

Comment: @RubenVerresen actually, wave function collapse and entanglement are intimately related.

Comment: @DanielSank (for the benefit of the masses, you know this for sure) the intimate relation is the last comment of Ruben's. The entanglement gets lost to the environment very easily.

Comment: @RubenVerresen In a maximally entangled state, where $|\psi_1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ a_4 \end{bmatrix}$ becomes  $|\psi_2\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}$,  (assuming normalization for both vectors) I think it is irreversible. The interaction hamiltonian that might produce it would have to be non-hermitian, I think.

Comment: @RubenVerresen OK, so it looks like some entanglements can be produced by a unitary time evolution operator (which makes them reversible, see "http://www.tau.ac.il/~yakir/yahp/yh25.pdf"  p, 573, eq. 2 for a hermitian interaction hamiltonian form similar to what is used in Stern Gerlach), but some, like the maximally entangled state, above, cannot and are clearly irreversible.

Comment: @David Any pure state can be mapped to any other pure state by some unitary operator generated by some Hamiltonian (not necessarily local). If that is your only criterion for reversibility, then any mapping from one pure state to another is reversible. Perhaps you need to clarify what your definition of reversibility is?

Comment: @JoelKlassen Thank you. So, there is a unitary matrix such that $\hat{U}\begin{bmatrix}
   a_1b_1 \\
    a_1b_2 \\
    a_2b_1 \\
    a_2b_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
   (a_1b_1 )/((a_1b_1 )^2+(a_2b_2)^2)\\
   0\\
   0\\
   ( a_2b_2)/((a_1b_1 )^2+(a_2b_2)^2)
\end{bmatrix} $?